# Avoid searching all documents when query field is unique?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new to mongoDB and I'm trying to understand how to fetch data from the database

I have a collection containing month wise documents, an example of the collection would be:

```
{
  MonthYear: "05-2023",
  ...
}

{
  MonthYear: "06-2023",
  ...
}

{
  MonthYear: "07-2023",
  ...
}
```

When I search a collection as such:

```
db.collection.find({"MonthYear": "06-2023"}).explain("executionStats")
```

> ```
> "executionStats": {
>     "executionStages": {
>       ...
>       "docsExamined": 3,
>     }
> ...
> }
> ```

It searches through all the available documents (which may be a huge quantity) till it finds the date, which seems like a waste when the `MonthYear` is always unique and hence should be known exactly where to look i.e. with no looping search

So my question is should I

1. Make a custom `_id` from `MonthYear` since it is always unique?
2. or should I index `MonthYear` and if I should, will it lead to any performance loss?

Or should I be taking a completely different approach?

Comment: I think either of those approaches is perfectly valid. Have you tried them and encountered any specific problem with them?

Comment: @user20042973 No not yet, I just wanted to make sure I'm taking the right path before starting